# Typescript recursive mapped typed with infer

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following type generated by typechain-ethers

```
type PromiseOrValue<T> = T | Promise<T>

type Generated = {
  foo: PromiseOrValue<string>
  bar: PromiseOrValue<BigNumber>
  baz: {
     hello: PromiseOrValue<number>
     world: PromiseOrValue<string>
  }
}
```

and created `Unwrap` to remove `PromiseOrValue`

```
type Unwrap<T> = {[K in keyof T]: T[K] extends PromiseOrValue<infer U> ? U : Unwrap<T[K]>}
```

but using this doesn't unwrap inner `baz` object

Is this even possible or I'm just missing something?

unwrap inner object

Comment: The problem seems to be that `{ hello: PromiseOrValue<number>, world: PromiseOrValue<string> }` extends `PromiseOrValue<T>` when `T = { hello: PromiseOrValue<number>, world: PromiseOrValue<string> }`. One fix would be to restrict the types `T` can be: `type PromiseOrValue<T extends string | number | BigNumber> = T | Promise<T>`.

Comment: Try `Unwrap<U>` instead of `U`

Comment: It strongly depends on your use cases; the simplest approach is to just unwrap any possible promises using [`Awaited`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#the-awaited-type-and-promise-improvements), as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/Wzx71N). Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?